# How to keep transparency intact when reading an image? (Java)

Tags: java, image, graphics, awt, javax.imageio

I'm having a problem with keeping my image transparent.

Let's say we have an image called `imageA.png` and we want to import it. To keep it accessable  for other methods we will first declare this:

```
private BufferedImage imageA;
```

And then import it:

```
className(){
    try{
        imageA = ImageIO.read(className.class.getResourceAsStream("floor.png"));
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then we can use it in a `paintComponent` method, as follows:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(imageA, 0, 0, null);
    //using Graphics.drawImage(Image img, int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2,int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2, ImageObserver observer) in the real program, don't know if that matters?
}
```

Now let's say that in my original picture, `imageA.png` there was a transparent area, it's now lost for some reason. At least, in my output. In the program that I use this way of drawing an image I draw it on top of another image, but see white where it's transparent in the original image. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do not call `repaint` inside `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent()` first for painting the background color. In the constructor or so do `setBackground(Color.CYAN);` to check transparency.

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot, and a link to the floor.png? ImageIO will keep transparent areas of a PNG transparent, my guess is that your component has a background that is confusing you. Try setOpaque(false). Also, if you wonder if something matters, try it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

to code posted here

- add `super.paintComponent(g)`, to clear previous painting, otherwise painting cumulated
- do not to call `repaint();` inside `paintComponent`, because can to caused endless loop, from inner `repaint();`, this method is used programatically for repainting, e.g. best of ways if from `Swing Timer`

to your question

- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with BuferredImage generated from code or linked from intenet sites

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need `setOpaque(false)` in your component (the one that overrides `paintComponent(Graphics g)`).

ImageIO keeps transparent parts of images transparent.